# ReactJS view handling on same component with different data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have an array of object which iterated using map to show respecting value of each object inside the array.

```
arrOfObj = [
  {name:"left",value:"Value of content left"},
  {name:"mid",value:"Value of content mid"},
  {name:"right",value:"Value of content right"}
]
```

Let's say I have a component "Card" that receive array of object from props, and then render received props value as rows of each key and object.

1. Left | Value of content left
2. Mid | Value of content mid
3. Right | Value of content right

...in a 1 column view.

Now let say I wanted it to show it as separate 3 column, and I read the 'name' to decide which one its belongs to. So it became like :

1. Value of content left **|** Value of content mid **|** Value of content right

My question is, should I render the "Card" 3 times (which is looks like the obvious solution), but then what about if I wanted to do an API call inside each component, but only used it on 1 side (left/mid/right) only. How to make it not called three times?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What about writing a condition for the `name` value, and based on it, you can separate your data into 3 columns?

Comment: This is a solution indeed, but I use the "Card" component to call an API that only needed by the "left", then with this solution, it'll be called 3 times

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this case with **compound component pattern**

Here is an article that describes it :

https://blog.logrocket.com/guide-to-react-compound-components-9c4b3eb482e9